# log4j.properties does not have effects on logging in activeJDBC

Tags: log4j, activejdbc, javalite

I am currently working on a simple web application using javalite webactive and activeJDBC. To start with javalite I simply used https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-simple/ and expanded from there.

One thing which I would like to change, now that I have already implemented a few controllers and models I want to customize the logger:

`[qtp1442407170-13] INFO org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher - {"controller":"app.controllers.HomeController","duration_millis":685,"remote_ip":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","method":"GET","action":"index","url":"http://localhost:8080/home/index","status":200}`.

I don't really get what the prefix represents hence I would like to change that part to show date and timestamps.

Following http://javalite.io/logging#log4j-configuration I should be able to customize the logging via `log4j.properties` in `src/main/resources`, but this does not seem to make any difference.

The files content:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %4p %c{1} - %m%n
```

I suspect that I have somehow overwritten the default logger, although I did not change anything related in the `pom.xml` or `Main.java`.

Am I missing something or could it be that the changes somehow get overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a method I have used on all my JavaLite ActiveWeb projects. The requirements are:

1. I want to log to a console while development - for convenience.
2. I want to log to a file in any other environment
3. I want my log file to have a JSON format  because I can analyze it in Splunk, ElasticSearch or any other similar tool.

So, I augmented the [ActiveWeb](https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-simple) with this [commit](https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-simple/commit/22f87c67a20e6aef17c7511600d63922a6a1b37b).

Let's do it step by step:

1. Add a property to the pom file `<logger-name>CONSOLE</logger-name>`
2. Add a file log4j.properties with this content:

```

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ${logger-name}
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %4p [%t]: %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/activeweb-simple.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.javalite.logging.JsonLog4jLayout
```

```

3. Add an SLF4J dependency to integrate it with Log4J:

```

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

```

4. Add a profile to the pom:

`<profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>file_log</id>
                <properties>
                    <logger-name>FILE</logger-name>
                </properties>
            </profile>
      </profiles>`

5. Add property filtering to pom:

`<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
    </resources>`

Lets see how this is working.

When you run the program in a development environment without a profile, maven replaces `${logger-name}`  in your `log4j.properties` file for `CONSOLE`. This way, you use the CONSOLE logger, and everything is printed to your console. If you run your program with profile `-Pfile_log`, then you Maven will replace  `${logger-name}` with `FILE`, so Log4J will log to a corresponding file.

Additionally, see that the console layout is `org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`, but the file layout is `org.javalite.logging.JsonLog4jLayout`. The `org.javalite.logging.JsonLog4jLayout` is a JavaLite integration with Log4J built specifically to integrate with Log4J and produce a JSON output.

So, how do you use it? In a development environment you do not need to do anything special, it just works. When you need to build it, run `mvn package -Pfile_log` -

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it!